# Python: iterate over dictionary keys by sorted value

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I need to iterate through a dictionary's keys but do it in an order specified by the value.

Example:

```
myDict = {ID1: 50, ID2: 40, ID3: 60}
```

I would like to somehow do this:

```
for keyCorrespondingToTheValue in sorted(myDict.values()):
```

--> How can I make this happen?

If the value is a ranking, I wan to go through each ID in order by ranking. I can do this by reversing the key/values in the dictionary, but I don't want to because there is no guarantee that the ranking values are unique.

Answer (score 6):

```
for key in sorted(myDict, key=myDict.get)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can sort `myDict.items` like so:

```
>>> myDict = {'ID1': 50, 'ID2': 40, 'ID3': 60}
>>> for item in sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
...     item
...
('ID2', 40)
('ID1', 50)
('ID3', 60)
>>> for key, _ in sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
...     key
...
'ID2'
'ID1'
'ID3'
>>>
```

The important part here is the [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) of `sorted`, which allows you to specify how you want each item sorted.  In this case, we sort on each key's value.

You may also want to read [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in the documentation to get a better understanding of how to use `sorted` and `key`.

Comment: Thanks! How do I sort it from largest -> smallest?

Comment: @JessicaDow - You can simply set the `reverse` parameter to `True`: `for item in sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):`

Comment: A reference to the "Sorting HOW TO" in the python docs might be nice:  https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: @BHM - Added for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
for key in sorted(myDict, key=lambda k: myDict[k]):
    ...
```